# ssh still asking for password after ssh-copy-id

Tags: ssh

```
[root@spectrumscale ~]# chmod 700 .ssh
[root@spectrumscale ~]# cd .ssh
[root@spectrumscale .ssh]# ssh-keygen -t rsa 
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/root/.ssh/id_rsa): 
/root/.ssh/id_rsa already exists.
Overwrite (y/n)? y
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
05:63:ff:2a:82:fc:c9:31:87:fc:a1:61:dc:4e:5a:52 root@spectrumscale
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|        +        |
|       . +       |
|          o      |
|         . .     |
|        E   .    |
|   . + +   .     |
|    o @ B .      |
|     + / o       |
|      * o        |
+-----------------+
[root@spectrumscale .ssh]#  ssh-copy-id -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@192.168.1.215
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
root@192.168.1.215's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
root@192.168.1.215's password: 

Number of key(s) added: 1
```

Now try logging into the machine, with:   `ssh 'root@192.168.1.215'"`and check to make sure that only the key(s) you wanted were added.

```
[root@spectrumscale .ssh]# ssh 192.168.1.215
root@192.168.1.215's password: 
Last failed login: Tue Nov 12 17:47:37 IST 2019 from 192.168.1.203 on ssh:notty
There was 1 failed login attempt since the last successful login.
Last login: Tue Nov 12 14:44:01 2019 from localhost
```

Comment: You also need to configure the sshd daemon on the server to use keys for authentication (and disable password access). Lots of tutorials on the internet, e.g. https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openssh-server.html

Comment: Edit make the code and question more readable!

Comment: ssh is picky about permissions on files and directories and I'm not sure if `ssh-copy-id` fixes this in cases where they are too permissive. Try this: `ssh 192.168.1.215 'mkdir -p .ssh; chmod go-w . .ssh; chmod ugo-x,go-w .ssh/authorized_keys'`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Comment: What's do you see in `/var/log/auth.log`

Answer (score 9):

You have to diagnose the root cause for this issue. You can find this by reading logs related `sshd` using `journalctl` command on the system you want to login.

Reading logs :

```
journalctl -t sshd
```

If the log shows some thing similar to *Authentication refused:
bad ownership or modes for directory*, this is due to **bad ownership** or **modes** for directory `/home/<your_user>/.ssh`.

fixing permissions by

```
chmod go-w /home/<your_user>
chmod 700 /home/<your_user>/.ssh
chmod 600 /home/<your_user>/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Also make sure that inside sshd configuration file  `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, make sure that `PubkeyAuthentication` is not commented and set `yes`.

Inside */etc/ssh/sshd_config* make sure these is a line,

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

It might needed to **restart** sshd service after edit in *sshd configuration file*.

```
sudo service sshd restart
```

This worked for me and hope this helps!.

Comment: Fixing permissions did it! For me, things went wrong when I added another user in the system... Fixed now!

Answer (score 1):

If you have verified all your permissions are correct, but are still being prompted for a password, make sure to add the below line to the file **/etc/ssh/sshd_config** *on the system you want to login to without a password*. This will allow the SSH daemon to accept ssh-rsa key types

```
pubkeyacceptedkeytypes ssh-rsa
```

After doing this, simply run the command `service sshd restart` and passwordless login should work now

Comment: Doesn't work. ```ubuntu@xxxxxxxx:~$ pubkeyacceptedkeytypes ssh-rsa
-bash: pubkeyacceptedkeytypes: command not found```

Comment: hello, this is not a bash command. It is a line that needs to be added to the file named /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Answer (score 0):

Not directly related to the situation in question, but in my case, forceing `ssh-copy-id` using `-f` option (on **Windows**) to copy the content of a `.pub` file **with BOM** resulted in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` not being read correctly and ssh requiring a password. The solution in this case is to remove unnecessary characters by `nano ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, etc.